# Converting epoch time stamp to readable date not working

Tags: java, android, timestamp, epoch

I'm trying to use this code to convert the timestamp i have but the output is completely wrong, the output is 17/01/1970 16:56:28!!! it should be 8/7/2014 5:14:59 PM

```
Date date = new Date(1407388499);
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
String formatted = format.format(date);
System.out.println(formatted);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
formatted = format.format(date);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Help me please

Comment: Date expects a number of milliseconds, not seconds, since the epoch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date is not long enough

```
new Date(1407388499);
Sat Jan 17 1970 15:56:28 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)
new Date(1407388499000);
Thu Aug 07 2014 14:14:59 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)
```

The value should be a Long that is the number of millseconds

**Edit**

So if your received number is

```
 int dt = 1407388499:
```

Then you need to do

```
Date date = new Date(1000L * dt);
```

Comment: but thats the number i receive from the webservice, so i have no control over it, i receive it as a string, then i convert it

Comment: just multiply it but 1000

Comment: I have edited my answer.  Just make sure that your int gets cast to a long

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The root cause of the problem is that the [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) specifies **seconds** since the Epoch whereas [`java.util.Date(long date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-) expects the number of milliseconds since the Epoch. So, you need to convert the Unix time into milliseconds and then pass the same to `java.util.Date(long date)`.

However, the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1407388499);

        // Corresponding date-time in Australia/Sydney
        ZonedDateTime zdtSydney = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney"));
        System.out.println(zdtSydney);

        // Formatted
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(zdtSydney));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-08-07T15:14:59+10:00[Australia/Sydney]
07/08/2014 15:14:59
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Solution using the legacy API:**

Avoid performing calculations yourself if there is an OOTB (Out-Of-The-Box) API available for it e.g. [`TimeUnit#convert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1407388499, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
        System.out.println(format.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
07/08/2014 15:14:59
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>